# Axios post request with multiple parameters in vuex action

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Fetching API data with axios in vuex action:

```
actions: {
login ({commit}, payload) {
  axios.post(globalConfig.TOKEN_URL, {
    payload
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      commit('auth_success', resp.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
},
}
```

Component's method for sending the data:

```
methods: {
  authChatClient () {
    let payload = {
      name: this.clientFio,
      number: this.clientNumber
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('login', payload)
  },
}
```

However it won't work, since payload is an object, wrapped in a payload object. Is it possible to send multiple parameters from component's method to a vuex action?

Post request is looking like this: `payload: {name: "aaa", number: "111"}`

Comment: Do you have an error or something returned by Axios ?

Comment: It's not about the errors axios throws, i'm using an API that designed to receive params in the following style: `{"name": "string", "phone": "string"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vuex only allows the use of 1 parameter to an action. However, if I understand your question correctly, you can send multiple parameters to a vuex action if they are wrapped in an object. Example:

```
login({commit}, {name, number /*, ...more here*/}) {
    axios.post(globalConfig.TOKEN_URL, {
        name: name,
        number: number,
        /* more parameters here */
    })
    /* ... */
}
```

And you can call it with:

```
methods: {
  authChatClient () {
    let payload = {
      name: this.clientFio,
      number: this.clientNumber,
      /* more parameters */
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('login', payload)
  },
}
```

Comment: I've tried everything, except destructuring arguments thing, thanks. But why vuex actions are not accepting multiple parameters by default? Do i use it in a wrong way?

Comment: It's not that Vuex actions don't accept multiple parameters _by default_, it's like that _always_. The thing is if you use object destruction you are technically only passing 1 parameter which is the object itself, so Vuex is happy. As for your usage, you aren't using it wrong since I see a lot of people using it this way, including myself.

Comment: also could you explain, please, why when i set different key name in axios's requiest, like: `name: name, phone: number`, it's just omitting the phone number on post request?

Comment: Could you show the relevent code perhaps? I don't have much experience with axios myself but I'd be happy to take look